# Page doesn't appear in search results

Tags: 7, views, search

I created a view (page) which shows a list of nodes of a certain content type. This page doesn't show up when searching the site.

Is this expected behavior? Is there any way to make the page show up in a search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question: Yes, this is the expected behavior. Views pages are not indexed by Drupal core search.

For the second question, Drupal core search is limited. More is possible by using Apache Solr search integration.
According to https://www.drupal.org/node/2570521, https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_nan is an example of a module that may do what you need. But you would need access to a Solr server.

Comment: Is there a way to make a Views page indexed? Or would a workaround be to make a page and add the View as a block to it?

Comment: @rarelyred that wouldn't work, as the block would not be the 'content' of the page. So it would still not index the view part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a page view, I've created a block view and added it to an actual page (content). This works in my particular case and allows the site to index the page to show up in a search. It may not be fancy but I don't have to add a module to make it happen.

Thanks to user [cilefen](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/17684/cilefen) who answered my questions and got me here.